# Reference a value from CSV in User Defined Variable in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a CSV Data Set Config,

[image]

I want to reference the variable `Stack` in my User Defined Variables and I have done it as follows,

I have used the `__eval` function to read the `Stack` variable

[image]

But in the request, I still see

```
https://${Stack}.testing.com
```

But I would like to see the value of the variable `Stack` from the CSV file.

I have tried the following,

```
__eval(${Stack}).testing.com  ->  ${Stack}.testing.com
__evalVar(Stack).testing.com  ->  .testing.com
${Stack}.testing.com          ->  ${Stack}.testing.com
```

Please advise on how can I reference the variable from CSV data set config in a User defined variable.

Thanks

Comment: Use just `${Stack}` in your test plan. This will retrieve the value from the CSV.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the value from the CSV by using `${Stack}`.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam On using `${Stack}` in User Defined Variable, I get `${Stack}` I dont get the value of Stack.

Comment: Can you post your jmeter.log info.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam I reference a variable from CSV in UDV and I use that UDV in my requests. If I directly use the variable from CSV in my request that works as you said.

Comment: You can cannot use the `${Stack}` in the User Defined Variables.

Comment: `Note that the Test Plan cannot refer to variables it defines.` 
`If you need to construct other variables from the Test Plan variables, use a User Defined Variables test element.`

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam Thank you for your comment, you can post this as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: Done. Please accept. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do it using CSV Data Set Config as it is getting initialised **after** User Defined Variables, however you should be able to use [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) instead like:

```
${__CSVRead(users/login.csv,3)}.testing.com
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter CSVRead in UDV]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on the above and other JMeter functions.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan), you cannot refer to variables it defines in the **Test Plan - User defined variables**.

> > Note that the Test Plan cannot refer to variables it defines.